# Excel, How do you make the the exponent number of e+11 to become e+12

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

356810115212.947 is display as 3.5681E+11 in Excel. I want it to be display as 0.3568E+12, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the cell and select "Format Cells...".

Set the Category to "Custom" and enter the following as format : `.0000E+00`,
then click OK.

For your example of `356810115212.947`, I get :

[image]

Comment: `###.0E+00` will generally display with an exponent divisible by three (3), i.e. aligned with prefixes; the above will become `356.8E+09` by that though.

Comment: @Hannu to be honest that would be scientifically preferable. If you have "0.2e+6" then I'd say your already at the wrong SI prefix level and should change. Using a multiple of 3 for SI suffixes should have a three digits available before the decimal place and at least one of them should be used, not none of them. If anything I'd say your comment is the correct answer personally.

Answer (score 1):

For "engineering correct" display of numbers with exponents,
i.e. to align with prefixes (exponent divisible by 3),
you might wish to use `###.0E+00` as custom/user formatting;
this isn't what was asked for though, as the above will become `356.8E+09` i.e. "356 T"

Answer (score 0):

```
="0."&IF(A1<10000,A1,LEFT(LEFT(A1,5)+5,4))&"E+"&LEN(INT(A1))
```

should work just fine

idea : manually concatenate all required component to make up the not-so scientific exponent notation. +5 is to cater for round up .

catch : works on positive, >1, numbers only. need to work out a different (but similar) one for other scale. Then can us if to 'combine' it as a formula.